# HTML Button not working with inline javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an inline javascript to test a button but the button isn't working when clicked.

I thought maybe the js code is wrong but I tested the button with a simple alert and it still not working can you help pls? Here is the HTML / and a sample js script.

```js
function calcEquation() {
  alert("hello");
```

```html
<form id="form-ckd" method="post">
  <div id="ckd-calc">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header py-3">
        <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">CKD calculator</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Sex of patient:</p>
        <div>
          <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input type="radio" name="sex-ckd" value="m"> Male
                    </label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input type="radio" name="sex-ckd" value="f"> Female
                    </label>
          <br /><br />
          <p>Ethnicity:</p>
          <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input type="radio" name="race-ckd" value="b"> Black
                    </label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input type="radio" name="race-ckd" value="o"> Other
                    </label>
          <br /><br />
          <p>Age of patient (years):</p>
          <input type="number" min="1" max="120" name="age-ckd" />
          <br /><br />
          <p>Serum creatinine (micromol/L):</p>
          <input type="number" min="1" max="120" name="serum-ckd" />
          <br />
        </div>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <div id="ckd-result">
          <h5 id="outs-ckd"></h5>
          <p>Glomerular Filtration Rate by the MDRD Equation: <a href="https://www.mdcalc.com/mdrd-gfr-equation#evidence" style="color:white;"><u> mdcalc website</u></a></p>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="calcEquation();">Calculate</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="popup.hideEquationFormPopup();">Close</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="resetCKD();">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Check out your console. It's telling you what's wrong. syntax error.

Comment: Also, it's `"text/javascript"` and not `text/javascript`. Attributes must always be wrapped in quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  <script type=text/javascript>
        function calcEquation(){
          alert("hello");
  </script>
```

I think you forgot to close the function with `}` in the end.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you've missed a closed curly bracket on the function calcEquation :) .

```html
<script type=text/javascript>
        function calcEquation(){
          alert("hello");}
  </script>




    <form id="form-ckd" method="post">
      <div id="ckd-calc">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header py-3">
              <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">CKD calculator</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <p>Sex of patient:</p>
              <div>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" name="sex-ckd" value="m"> Male
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" name="sex-ckd" value="f"> Female
                </label>
                <br /><br />
                <p>Ethnicity:</p>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" name="race-ckd" value="b"> Black
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" name="race-ckd" value="o"> Other
                </label>
                <br /><br />
                <p>Age of patient (years):</p>
                <input type="number" min="1" max="120" name="age-ckd" />
                <br /><br />
                <p>Serum creatinine (micromol/L):</p>
                <input type="number" min="1" max="120" name="serum-ckd" />
                <br />
              </div>
              <br />
              <hr />
              <div id="ckd-result">
                <h5 id="outs-ckd" ></h5>
                <p >Glomerular Filtration Rate by the MDRD Equation: <a href="https://www.mdcalc.com/mdrd-gfr-equation#evidence" style="color:white;"><u> mdcalc website</u></a></p>
              </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="calcEquation();">Calculate</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="popup.hideEquationFormPopup();">Close</button>
              <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="resetCKD();">Reset</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>

    </form>
```